# How to get a non-cursive minuscule kappa in \textgreek{fusik'h} (physics)?

Tags: symbols, luatex, greek

I'm trying to write "physics" in Greek by using "textgreek". It replaces the input text "k" with the cursive "kappa", but I want the more common non-cursive minuscule kappa.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,20pt]{book}

\usepackage[greek,portuges,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{fusik'h}

\end{document}
```

That's what I get:

[image: \textgreek{fusik'h} as in my output pdf.]

But when I copy it and paste it here, it's how I would like it to look:

φυσική

So I guess it's something about character configuration.

I'm using Overleaf with LuaLatex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The two forms are just different typographic realizations of the same character, by two different fonts. Unicode has “Greek small letter kappa U+03BA” and “Greek kappa symbol U+03F0”, but their realizations are font dependent.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]. This *is* the upright kappa provided by `textgreek`. If you don't like it you need another font.

Comment: That is the *normal* to write Greek. What you want is a sans-serif Greek font. `Open sans` might be a solution.

Comment: BTW: if you use LuaLaTeX you should remove `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a comparison of the kappa in some freely available Greek fonts in TeX Live:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  #1: {\fontencoding{LGR}\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont κ}%
}

\begin{document}

\test{cmr}

\test{artemisia}

\test{gfsbaskerville}

\test{bodoni}

\test{complutum}

\test{udidot}

\test{neohellenic}

\test{porson}

\test{solomos}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the same letter is rendered differently in different fonts: it's just a question of taste and design. There is no “official” shape of the *glyph* kappa that realizes in print the *character* kappa.

Unicode has the code point U+03F0 for GREEK KAPPA SYMBOL; it has similar code points for beta, epsilon, sigma, phi, pi, rho, theta. However it would be wrong to use U+03F0 for the letter (U+03BA).

Suppose you decide for Artemisia; you can do

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[greek,brazilian]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage{textgreek}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{fusik'h}

\end{document}
```

Note that `utf8x` is not really recommended and even `utf8` is no longer needed; also, you shouldn't load both `portugues` and `brazilian`.

The output would be

[image]

Oh, well! GFS Artemisia has a quite peculiar realization of the glyph eta!

However, the list is up there, decide by yourself.

Comment: i'm no greek scholar, but people i've known who were, considered porson greek pretty close to "standard".  from the appearance of the kappa, i *can* say it's the form i'm most familiar with.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In the Italian schools where ancient Greek is taught, the “cursive” form is the commonly used one. I think it's similar to the open or closed form for theta: here we use the open one, whereas in the US the closed form is common.

Comment: ah, another "cultural difference".  (when i took classes in modern greek, i also learned a cursive beta, which i have seen only rarely in print.  it never got requested in a tex font that i know of.  (certainly not for math.)

Comment: I've chosen Porson because of Barbara comment about it looking more "standard", but Artemisia is really very beautiful and I may change my mind in favor of it.